# press F1 to open sub menuitem in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Instead of using Alt + F to open the menu "File", I want to change the holy key F1, how do I do that? Thanks!

```
 <Grid>
    <Menu Background="Transparent">
        <MenuItem x:Name="asd" Header="_File">
            <MenuItem x:Name="a"  Header="1. _New" InputGestureText="ALT-N" Margin="0,18,0,0"/>
            <MenuItem Header="2. _Open" InputGestureText="Alt+O"/>
            <MenuItem Header="3. _Close"/>
            <MenuItem Header="4. Save"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="5. Delete" Margin="0,8,0,0"/>
            <MenuItem Header="6. Rename"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="7. Print" Margin="0,8,0,8"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="8. Format Disk" Margin="0,8,0,8"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="9. MINE(Decode)" Margin="0,8,0,8"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Comment: For future questions it is encouraged that you include notes on what you have attempted and what issues you had in your attempts.

Comment: Ok! I will note that

Comment: I pressed F1 but menu didn't open. I must preess "Alt" and then pressed "F1" for menu to open

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting the behaviour you desire would be to add an `PreviewKeyDown` event listener to your `Grid` or the parent.

```
<Grid PreviewKeyDown="Grid_PreviewKeyDown">
    <Menu Background="Transparent">
        <MenuItem x:Name="asd" Header="_File">
            <MenuItem x:Name="a"  Header="1. _New" InputGestureText="ALT-N" Margin="0,18,0,0"/>
            <MenuItem Header="2. _Open" InputGestureText="Alt+O"/>
            <MenuItem Header="3. _Close"/>
            <MenuItem Header="4. Save"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="5. Delete" Margin="0,8,0,0"/>
            <MenuItem Header="6. Rename"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="7. Print" Margin="0,8,0,8"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="8. Format Disk" Margin="0,8,0,8"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="9. MINE(Decode)" Margin="0,8,0,8"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Then in the underlying C# code add the following action event

```
private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F1) // This filters what key was pressed
    {
        asd.IsSubmenuOpen = true; // This opens the menu
        e.Handled = true; // Setting this to true prevents the any other events from occurring due to the key press
    }
}
```

Comment: I pressed F1 but menu didn't open. I must preess "Alt" and then pressed "F1" for menu to open